# How to create a transition matrix for a column in python?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I convert column B into the transition matrix in python?

Size of the matrix is 19 which is unique values in column B.
There are a total of 432 rows in the dataset.

```
time                A          B
2017-10-26 09:00:00  36       816
2017-10-26 10:45:00  43       816
2017-10-26 12:30:00  50       998
2017-10-26 12:45:00  51       750
2017-10-26 13:00:00  52       998
2017-10-26 13:15:00  53       998
2017-10-26 13:30:00  54       998
2017-10-26 14:00:00  56       998
2017-10-26 14:15:00  57       834
2017-10-26 14:30:00  58      1285
2017-10-26 14:45:00  59      1288
2017-10-26 23:45:00  95      1285
2017-10-27 03:00:00  12      1285
2017-10-27 03:30:00  14      1285
                             ... 
2017-11-02 14:00:00  56       998
2017-11-02 14:15:00  57       998
2017-11-02 14:30:00  58       998
2017-11-02 14:45:00  59       998
2017-11-02 15:00:00  60       816
2017-11-02 15:15:00  61       275
2017-11-02 15:30:00  62       225
2017-11-02 15:45:00  63      1288
2017-11-02 16:00:00  64      1088
2017-11-02 18:15:00  73      1285
2017-11-02 20:30:00  82      1285
2017-11-02 21:00:00  84      1088
2017-11-02 21:15:00  85      1088
2017-11-02 21:30:00  86      1088
2017-11-02 22:00:00  88      1088
2017-11-02 22:30:00  90      1088
2017-11-02 23:00:00  92      1088
2017-11-02 23:30:00  94      1088
2017-11-02 23:45:00  95      1088
```

The matrix should contain the number of transition between them.

```
 B -----------------1088------1288----------------------------
B  
.
.
1088                   8         2
.
.
.
.
.            Number of transitions between them.
..
.
.
```

Comment: if you use `pandas` then add tag `pandas`.

Comment: in pure Python you could use `zip(B, B[1:])` to create pairs and `Counter()` to count them.  More work would need to fill list/matrix with this data. In `pandas` you could use `shift()` to create column `B[1:]` and `groupby` to count them. Again more work need to fill new `df` with results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use your data to create DataFrame only with column `B` but it should work also with all columns.

```
text = '''time                A          B
2017-10-26 09:00:00  36       816
2017-10-26 10:45:00  43       816
2017-10-26 12:30:00  50       998
2017-10-26 12:45:00  51       750
2017-10-26 13:00:00  52       998
2017-10-26 13:15:00  53       998
2017-10-26 13:30:00  54       998
2017-10-26 14:00:00  56       998
2017-10-26 14:15:00  57       834
2017-10-26 14:30:00  58      1285
2017-10-26 14:45:00  59      1288
2017-10-26 23:45:00  95      1285
2017-10-27 03:00:00  12      1285
2017-10-27 03:30:00  14      1285
2017-11-02 14:00:00  56       998
2017-11-02 14:15:00  57       998
2017-11-02 14:30:00  58       998
2017-11-02 14:45:00  59       998
2017-11-02 15:00:00  60       816
2017-11-02 15:15:00  61       275
2017-11-02 15:30:00  62       225
2017-11-02 15:45:00  63      1288
2017-11-02 16:00:00  64      1088
2017-11-02 18:15:00  73      1285
2017-11-02 20:30:00  82      1285
2017-11-02 21:00:00  84      1088
2017-11-02 21:15:00  85      1088
2017-11-02 21:30:00  86      1088
2017-11-02 22:00:00  88      1088
2017-11-02 22:30:00  90      1088
2017-11-02 23:00:00  92      1088
2017-11-02 23:30:00  94      1088
2017-11-02 23:45:00  95      1088'''

import pandas as pd

B = [int(row[29:].strip()) for row in text.split('\n') if 'B' not in row]
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': B})
```

I get unique values in colum to use it later to create matrix

```
numbers = sorted(df['B'].unique())
print(numbers)

[225, 275, 750, 816, 834, 998, 1088, 1285, 1288]
```

I create shifted column `C` so I have both values in every row

```
df['C'] = df.shift(-1)
print(df)

       B       C
0    816   816.0
1    816   998.0
2    998   750.0
3    750   998.0
```

I group by `['B', 'C']` so I can count pairs

```
groups = df.groupby(['B', 'C'])
counts = {i[0]:(len(i[1]) if i[0][0] != i[0][1] else 0) for i in groups} # don't count (816,816)
# counts = {i[0]:len(i[1]) for i in groups} # count even (816,816)
print(counts)

{(225, 1288.0): 2, (275, 225.0): 2, (750, 998.0): 2, (816, 275.0): 2, (816, 816.0): 2, (816, 998.0): 2, (834, 1285.0): 2, (998, 750.0): 2, (998, 816.0): 2, (998, 834.0): 2, (998, 998.0): 12, (1088, 1088.0): 14, (1088, 1285.0): 2, (1285, 998.0): 2, (1285, 1088.0): 2, (1285, 1285.0): 6, (1285, 1288.0): 2, (1288, 1088.0): 2, (1288, 1285.0): 2}
```

Now I can create matrix. Using `numbers` and `counts` I create column/Series (with correct `index`) and I add it to matrix.

```
matrix = pd.DataFrame()

for x in numbers:
    matrix[x] = pd.Series([counts.get((x,y), 0) for y in numbers], index=numbers)

print(matrix)
```

Result

```
      225  275  750  816  834  998  1088  1285  1288
225     0    2    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
275     0    0    0    2    0    0     0     0     0
750     0    0    0    0    0    2     0     0     0
816     0    0    0    2    0    2     0     0     0
834     0    0    0    0    0    2     0     0     0
998     0    0    2    2    0   12     0     2     0
1088    0    0    0    0    0    0    14     2     2
1285    0    0    0    0    2    0     2     6     2
1288    2    0    0    0    0    0     0     2     0
```

Full example

```
text = '''time                A          B
2017-10-26 09:00:00  36       816
2017-10-26 10:45:00  43       816
2017-10-26 12:30:00  50       998
2017-10-26 12:45:00  51       750
2017-10-26 13:00:00  52       998
2017-10-26 13:15:00  53       998
2017-10-26 13:30:00  54       998
2017-10-26 14:00:00  56       998
2017-10-26 14:15:00  57       834
2017-10-26 14:30:00  58      1285
2017-10-26 14:45:00  59      1288
2017-10-26 23:45:00  95      1285
2017-10-27 03:00:00  12      1285
2017-10-27 03:30:00  14      1285
2017-11-02 14:00:00  56       998
2017-11-02 14:15:00  57       998
2017-11-02 14:30:00  58       998
2017-11-02 14:45:00  59       998
2017-11-02 15:00:00  60       816
2017-11-02 15:15:00  61       275
2017-11-02 15:30:00  62       225
2017-11-02 15:45:00  63      1288
2017-11-02 16:00:00  64      1088
2017-11-02 18:15:00  73      1285
2017-11-02 20:30:00  82      1285
2017-11-02 21:00:00  84      1088
2017-11-02 21:15:00  85      1088
2017-11-02 21:30:00  86      1088
2017-11-02 22:00:00  88      1088
2017-11-02 22:30:00  90      1088
2017-11-02 23:00:00  92      1088
2017-11-02 23:30:00  94      1088
2017-11-02 23:45:00  95      1088'''

import pandas as pd

B = [int(row[29:].strip()) for row in text.split('\n') if 'B' not in row]
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': B})

numbers = sorted(df['B'].unique())
print(numbers)

df['C'] = df.shift(-1)
print(df)

groups = df.groupby(['B', 'C'])
counts = {i[0]:(len(i[1]) if i[0][0] != i[0][1] else 0) for i in groups} # don't count (816,816)
# counts = {i[0]:len(i[1]) for i in groups} # count even (816,816)
print(counts)

matrix = pd.DataFrame()

for x in numbers:
    matrix[str(x)] = pd.Series([counts.get((x,y), 0) for y in numbers], index=numbers)

print(matrix)
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
counts = {i[0]:(len(i[1]) if i[0][0] != i[0][1] else 0) for i in groups} # don't count (816,816)
```

as normal `for` loop

```
counts = {}
for pair, group in groups:
    if pair[0] != pair[1]:  # don't count (816,816)
        counts[pair] = len(group)
    else:  
        counts[pair] = 0
```

Invert value when it is bigger thant 10

```
counts = {}
for pair, group in groups:
    if pair[0] != pair[1]:  # don't count (816,816)
        count = len(group)
        if count > 10 :
            counts[pair] = -count
        else
            counts[pair] = count
    else:  
        counts[pair] = 0
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
counts = {}
for pair, group in groups:
    if pair[0] != pair[1]:  # don't count (816,816)

        #counts[(A,B)] = len((A,B)) + len((B,A)) 
        if pair not in counts:
            counts[pair] = len(group) # put first value
        else:
            counts[pair] += len(group) # add second value

        #counts[(B,A)] = len((A,B)) + len((B,A)) 
        if (pair[1],pair[0]) not in counts:
            counts[(pair[1],pair[0])] = len(group) # put first value
        else:
            counts[(pair[1],pair[0])] += len(group) # add second value
    else:  
        counts[pair] = 0 # (816,816) gives 0

#counts[(A,B)] == counts[(B,A)]

counts_2 = {}               
for pair, count in counts.items():
    if count > 10 :
        counts_2[pair] = -count
    else:
        counts_2[pair] = count

matrix = pd.DataFrame()

for x in numbers:
    matrix[str(x)] = pd.Series([counts_2.get((x,y), 0) for y in numbers], index=numbers)

print(matrix)
```

Comment: Thanks Furas. But the number of transitions in the results are more than the number of rows. I think it should be equal to the rows.

Comment: And how can we fill 0 where there is a transition between the same numbers. Example: if the transition is (1088.0, 1088.0): 411 then we should fill 0 in the place of 411.

Comment: it should be `rows-1` because last row has no transition. Now I see problem - it have to  be `len(i[1])` instead of `i[1].size` because group has `len(i[1])` rows but every row has two element so `i[1].size = 2*len(i[1])`

Comment: `counts = {i[0]:len(i[1]) if i[0][0] != i[0][1] else 0 for i in groups}` it should give `(1088.0, 1088.0): 0`

Comment: Can we create a distance matrix for the above example. If the transition count is <10 then the distance remains same. if the transition count is >10 then the distance is inverse. (((( Here column A is random points on the map. If there is more transition its means that the distance between the points is less.)))

Comment: Hello Furas. In the transition count if the pair (225,275):2 and (275,225):3 then the result in the matrix should be (225,275):5, which is 2+3. How can we do this?

Comment: `sorted( (225,275) )` and `sorted( (275,225) )` gives `[225,275]` so it can be used to find two pairs which we have to cumulate. But it will need little more code - I will see it later.

Comment: I made different. I split `for` loop on two loops. First counts `counts[(A,B)] = len((A,B)) + len((B,A))` and `counts[(B,A)] = len((A,B)) + len((B,A)) `. Second change sigh when `count > 10`

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, pandas based approach. Note I've used shift(1) which means transition is the next number:

```
text = '''time                A          B
2017-10-26 09:00:00  36       816
2017-10-26 10:45:00  43       816
2017-10-26 12:30:00  50       998
2017-10-26 12:45:00  51       750
2017-10-26 13:00:00  52       998
2017-10-26 13:15:00  53       998
2017-10-26 13:30:00  54       998
2017-10-26 14:00:00  56       998
2017-10-26 14:15:00  57       834
2017-10-26 14:30:00  58      1285
2017-10-26 14:45:00  59      1288
2017-10-26 23:45:00  95      1285
2017-10-27 03:00:00  12      1285
2017-10-27 03:30:00  14      1285
2017-11-02 14:00:00  56       998
2017-11-02 14:15:00  57       998
2017-11-02 14:30:00  58       998
2017-11-02 14:45:00  59       998
2017-11-02 15:00:00  60       816
2017-11-02 15:15:00  61       275
2017-11-02 15:30:00  62       225
2017-11-02 15:45:00  63      1288
2017-11-02 16:00:00  64      1088
2017-11-02 18:15:00  73      1285
2017-11-02 20:30:00  82      1285
2017-11-02 21:00:00  84      1088
2017-11-02 21:15:00  85      1088
2017-11-02 21:30:00  86      1088
2017-11-02 22:00:00  88      1088
2017-11-02 22:30:00  90      1088
2017-11-02 23:00:00  92      1088
2017-11-02 23:30:00  94      1088
2017-11-02 23:45:00  95      1088'''

import pandas as pd

B = [int(row[29:].strip()) for row in text.split('\n') if 'B' not in row]
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': B})
# alternative approach
df['C'] = df['B'].shift(1)  # shift forward so B transitions to C

df['counts'] = 1  # add an arbirtary counts column for group by

# group together the combinations then unstack to get matrix
trans_matrix = df.groupby(['B', 'C']).count().unstack()

# max the columns a bit neater
trans_matrix.columns = trans_matrix.columns.droplevel()
```

The result is:

[image]

Which I think is correct, i.e the one time you observe 225, it then transitions to 1288. You would just divide through by the sample size to get a probability transition matrix for each value.